# Measure still picking up Filter Context

Tags: powerbi, dax

We have the following measure, which is being used in a card in the top right of a report just to let the user know what the maximum date is in the model - just so they have visibility of whether the report is the latest version.

Unfortunately when a date slicer in the report is changed the filter context changes the result of this card. The measure is as follows:

```
Max_DateTo = 
FORMAT(
    CALCULATE(
    MAX( tb_fact[DateTo] ),
    ALL ( tb_fact[DateTo] )
) + 1
,"DD MMM"
)
```

How do we change the above to always ignore all filter context?

Comment: I presume you have a relationship between tb_fact[DateTo] and a Date table?

Comment: @Olly No - it is getting everything from a single table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you are only overwriting the filter on [dateTo], so all other filters still apply. You want to overrule all filters on the table.

Formula to calculate your last date with context filtering

```
MaxDate:=max('Date'[Date])
```

Remove the context filter on your table:

```
maxdate no context:=CALCULATE([MaxDate],ALL('Date'))
```